# Deleting small polygons in an sf-object

Tags: r, polygon

I have an sf-object (shp downloadable here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ERFdsqDGLH1a_FbxwawE_gPm0Au0Q9vT) with multiple glaciers.

I want to delete glaciers smaller than 0.05km² by using a for-loop. I think, I just got something wrong in the last loop, but to be reproducable: my general code so far is

```
glaciers <- readOGR("C:/***", "Glacier_Clip_Polygon")
glaciers_sf <- st_as_sf(glaciers)
glaciers_comb <- st_union(glaciers_sf) # some glaciers are separated into different polygons so I merged them
glaciers_comb <- st_cast(glaciers_comb, "POLYGON")
```

Then I access the area of the different polygons and store them in a vector to be used in a loop.

```
area <- st_area(glaciers_comb)
area_v <- as.vector(area)

area_cutoff <- vector("numeric")

for(i in 1:length(area_v)) {
    if(area_v[i]>50000)
    area_cutoff[i] <- area_v[i]
}

area_cutoff[is.na(area_cutoff)] <- 0
```

Now I want R to loop through this vector and only save the big polygons to the original object.

```
for(i in 1:length(area_cutoff)){
  if(area_cutoff[i]>1)
  glaciers_comb[i] <- glaciers_comb[i]
}
```

However, R `glaciers_comb`does not change when I run this loop. Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in this:

```
for(i in 1:length(area_cutoff)){
  if(area_cutoff[i]>1)
   glaciers_comb[i] <- glaciers_comb[i]
}
```

If the `if` condition is true you are replacing element `i` with element `i` - which is no replacement. And when the `if` condition isn't true then element `i` is unchanged. So nothing changes.

You can do what you want with a one-liner:

```
glaciers_large <- glaciers_comb[as.numeric(st_area(glaciers_comb)) > 50000]
```

leaving 27 features:

```
> glaciers_large
Geometry set for 27 features 
geometry type:  POLYGON
```

This is basic R use of square brackets to subset elements of a vector by a true or false condition. The `as.numeric` is only needed because the area has units attached and otherwise you get:

```
> glaciers_large <- glaciers_comb[st_area(glaciers_comb) > 50000]
Error in Ops.units(st_area(glaciers_comb), 50000) : 
  both operands of the expression should be "units" objects
```

So really you should compare against a size in metres^2 using the `units` package:

```
> glaciers_large <- glaciers_comb[st_area(glaciers_comb) > units::set_units(50000,"m^2")]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer!